# Query with broken sub-select should result in error but returns rows

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I don't understand the behaviour in this case. In my understanding a query with an invalid sub-query should result in an error. But in this example it returns some rows.

Test-Data:

```
create table test_values ( tst_id number, tst_id2 number, tst_value varchar2( 10 ) );

create table test_lookup ( tst_id number, tst_value varchar2( 10 ) );

insert into test_values( tst_id, tst_id2, tst_value ) values ( 1, 2, 'a' );
insert into test_values( tst_id, tst_id2, tst_value ) values ( 1, 2, 'b' );
insert into test_values( tst_id, tst_id2, tst_value ) values ( 2, 2,'c' );
insert into test_values( tst_id, tst_id2, tst_value ) values ( 2, 2,'d' );

insert into test_lookup( tst_id, tst_value ) values ( 1, 'findMe' );

commit;
```

Works as expected:

```
select * from test_values where tst_id in ( select tst_id from test_lookup where tst_value = 'findMe' );

/*
    TST_ID    TST_ID2 TST_VALUE 
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2 b         
         1          2 a   
*/

select tst_id2 from test_lookup where tst_value = 'findMe'; 
--ORA-00904: "TST_ID2": invalid identifier
```

But the following query is also retrieving lines, obviously by taking the "test_id2"-column from the "test_values"-table and not from the "test_lookup"-table as stated in the sub-query and though NOT using aliases for inner and outer parts.

```
select * from test_values where tst_id in ( select tst_id2 from test_lookup where tst_value = 'findMe' );

/*
   TST_ID    TST_ID2 TST_VALUE  
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2 c         
         2          2 d         
*/
```

Comment: @vmachan the OP posted a complete testcase, including create table and insert statements. I'm not sure what extra information you're expecting the OP to add to their question!

Comment: I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774242/force-outer-select-to-fail-if-the-inner-select-contains-an-invalid-identifier . If you are asking how to change this behavior ... it seems that you can't.

Comment: Yep. It this use proper (but longer) code and everything's fine thing ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is because when an unaliased column doesn't exist in the subquery but does exist in the outer query, Oracle assumes you are referring to the column from the outer query.

With aliases, the query you're confused about would look like:

```
select *
from   test_values tv
where  tv.tst_id in (select tv.tst_id2
                     from   test_lookup tl
                     where  tl.tst_value = 'findMe');
```

Hopefully, that makes things clearer?

The issue you're seeing is a very good example of why you should always label your columns with which table they came from - it makes it much easier to maintain the query for a start!

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I'm still astonished that it works like this. Thinking not of a select but a somehow stored delete statement you might get to inadvertently delete lines from table "A"  by altering the columns of table "B" and not even touching the statement itself **urghs**. Ok, going to use aliases now whenever using more than one table ;)

Comment: @evilive it works like that because of correlated subqueries - e.g. `select * from table1 t1 where exists (select null from table2 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col1);`. I.e. the scope of the outer query extends to the top level of any subquery within it. So, if the query is explicit about which columns it's using, Oracle has to guess which table the column comes from. And props for spotting another case to support the use of aliases!

Comment: @evilive: this is actually not specific to Oracle. This is how name resolution is defined to work in the SQL standard

Answer (score 5):

When your 'broken' query is used as a subquery, it can still refer to the outer query's table columns; that's necessary for correlation to work. It's picking up the `tst_id2` column from the `test_values` table. If both tables had the same column then the inner table would take precedence, but that isn't the case here.

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357):

> Oracle resolves unqualified columns in the subquery by looking in the tables named in the subquery and then in the tables named in the parent statement.

You can see what's happening by adding table aliases; this still errors:

```
select * from test_values tv where tst_id in (
  select tl.tst_id2 from test_lookup tl where tl.tst_value = 'findMe' );

ORA-00904: "TL"."TST_ID2": invalid identifier
```

But this works:

```
select * from test_values tv where tst_id in (
  select tv.tst_id2 from test_lookup tl where tl.tst_value = 'findMe' );
```

It is explicitly using `test_values` column (via the `tv` alias); your original query was doing the same, but implicitly.

Comment: Thank you to, Boneist was a little faster

Comment: @evilive - not the first time, and probably not for the last time... I'll leave this here anyway as it's *slightly* different and has a doc link *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole hurrah for doc links! *{;-D (p.s. Happy New Year!)