# Force outer SELECT to fail if the inner SELECT contains an invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

If

```
SELECT ID FROM T2
```

**fails** with the following message:

> Error: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

why **doesn't**

```
SELECT * 
    FROM T1
    WHERE ID IN 
        ( 
            SELECT ID FROM T2
        )
```

**fail**? (it returns all entries from T1)

Is it possible to change this default behavior?
(running the same query, but getting an error instead of all rows)

---

I have:

- T1 with ID as column
- T2 with ID2 as column (T2 doesn't contain ID)

but let's say that I use `SELECT ID FROM T2` (see the example above) instead of `SELECT ID2 FROM T2` by mistake. In this situation nothing wrong happens because I use `SELECT ... IN SELECT ...`, but it could produce important damages if it would be replaced by `DELETE ... IN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593247/266304).

But you also asked: "Is it possible to change this default behavior?
(running the same query, but getting an error instead of all rows)" and expanded on that in a comment with "I want to force the failure for the same query, not to change the query to get the wanted result".

No, it isn't possible to change the behaviour. It's doing what [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357) says it should do:

> Oracle resolves unqualified columns in the subquery by looking in the tables named in the subquery and then in the tables named in the parent statement.

You can't make it stop looking at the parent statement and only resolve the unqualified alias inside the subquery. You would have to change the query to make it error. There is no reason *not* to qualify your identifiers, and plenty of reasons why you should, including that it can prevent you masking mistakes in your code.

Comment: Ok, I understand the importance of aliases. Because it seems that I can't prevent this, I hope that nobody that can run queries on the same database will use a `DELETE ... WHERE ... IN SELECT ...` without aliases.

Comment: @engineer - your coding standards could insist on them, and your code review process could catch both that they are missing and that a mistake like this has been made... that's the ideal, anyway *8-) I wouldn't expect anyone to be running ad hoc deletes without a good reason, and even then they should be being careful. Yeah, also the ideal...

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM T1
    WHERE ID IN 
        ( 
            SELECT T2.ID FROM T2
        )
```

Comment: I edited my post. I want to force the failure for the same query, not to change the query to get the wanted result.

Comment: This answers the question.  If you don't want to get the error, then always qualify your column names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I don't know if you are familiar with Hibernate (or another ORM), but to have an analogy ... if the default fetching strategy is lazy, then I can change it to eager. I don't modify the code (queries), but I give some instructions to Hibernate to change its default behavior.

Comment: I voted up your question because it answers to the question in title and can be really useful for the others, but I accepted the other answer because it's more focused on the details I provided in edit.

Comment: Fair enough.  I also had upvoted Alex's answer.  It's the best one.